# Weird output from GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

With the following code I get some unexpected output:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Activity numColumns: "+mGrid.getNumColumns());
Log.i(TAG, "Activity verticalSpace: "+mGrid.getVerticalSpacing());
Log.i(TAG, "Activity horizontalSpace: "+mGrid.getHorizontalSpacing());
```

The log output says:

```
09-17 10:39:26.083: I/MeMoGame(744):Activity numColumns: -1
09-17 10:39:26.083: I/MeMoGame(744):Activity verticalSpace: 7
09-17 10:39:26.083: I/MeMoGame(744): Activity horizontalSpace: 0
```

Which is totally weird because these are entered values in XML:

```
    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/grid_horizontal_space"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/grid_vertical_space"
    android:numColumns="4"
```

and:

```
    <dimen
    name="grid_horizontal_space">7dp</dimen>
    <dimen
    name="grid_vertical_space">7dp</dimen>
```

It looks like Android has begun some kind of lottery; or is there a reasonable explanation?

Comment: Instead of android:numColumns="4" specify android:columnCount="4"

Comment: @Zaps Is that documented? What about HorizontalSpacing?

Comment: @Zaps Nice try, but Android does not like it.

Comment: yes it is documented!!